# VSTS: Query based on observing user

Tags: azure-devops

I am working on some simple queries for Visual Studio Team Services. Is there a way to change the query result based on which user views it?
I know about the @Me operator but for this specific case I want to look for unassigned work items and filter them by current user.

There are 3 backlogs, and user A,B and C. User A is responsible to assign tasks for backlog1, user B for backlog2. I want to have a single dashboard with a query showing the unassigned task. So if user A opens the dashboard it should show all unassigned tasks for backlog1 and for user B all tasks from backlog2.

Comment: Is there any field in the work item indicates who should be responsible to it?

Comment: No thats the problem I am facing. I created team groups with the responsible users but I hoped for a way to access the user who is currently looking at the dashboard

Comment: Are these tasks linked to the backlogs and the backlog assigned to users?

Comment: the taks reside in a certain backlog (Team Project field), can you give a short headup how to assign user to a backlog? This sounds like a possible solution

Comment: What do you mean about "a certain backlog (Team Project field)"?

Comment: I have multiple backlogs. On of them (BL_M) is the master backlog, the rest are project related (BL_1-BL_X). Each backlog has a user who is responsible to accept new PBI in this backlog. I want to create a central dashboard in BL_M. One of the queries should show each user if (s)he has PBIs to accept. So the query would go along the lines: "See if in the backlogs assigned to the current user are PBIs with state==new". I am not able to get the link betwen the current user and the corresponding project. I know in which BL the PBIs are created and i also know the teams responsible for which BL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118877/discussion-between-floar-and-eddie-msft).

Comment: I thought your backlogs means PBI, sorry for misunderstand that.:( Base on your description, I'm afraid there isn't any way to achieve the feature you want. You need to create separated queries for all the backlogs.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has recently added the `@Me` token to all fields related to users.

This enables creating queries for the observing user - and in extension - personalised queries on the dashboard.

Additional info and the related docs [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/query-operators-variables?view=vsts#query-macros-or-variables)